# HikariCP with SpringBoot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hikaricp

I have configured the max. connection pool size of my SpringBoot application to 1 by using the following command:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=1
```

Is there any way to verify and confirm this change. I want to check that this is working for my application.

Comment: WHy bother with a connection pool if yuo aren't going to use it anyway?

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum!
Actually I need to change my connection pool size for some reason. If it works fine, I will use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the pool values in log, if you enable debug log for HikariCP.
HikariCP housekeeper thread logs pool information at fixed time interval.

Just set `com.zaxxer.hikari` logging level to `debug`.
In logback.xml you can do it like

```
<logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari" level="debug"/>
```

Or you can do it in `application.properties`

```
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=debug
```

In your console of log file you will find something similar like this.

```
DEBUG [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
```

`Total` value should not exceed `maximum-pool-size` value.